# Stuck filling an array using VBscript and a For Loop

Tags: vbscript

I have created an array to store some excel cell addresses, but while running through a portion of the array with a For Loop (because the values are in order for that portion of the data and its easier than doing each one at a time), but I get an error at line 22,(saData(i,1) = "D" count), right at the "count" variable but I cant figure out why.

```
'LOADING EXCEL CELL ADDRESS INTO INPUT ARRAY
 saData(0,1) = "C3"
 saData(1,1) = "F3"
 saData(2,1) = "C4"
 saData(3,1) = "F4"
 saData(4,1) = "F6"
 saData(5,1) = "C7"
 saData(6,1) = "F7"
 saData(7,1) = "C8"
 saData(8,1) = "C9"
 saData(9,1) = "F9"
 saData(10,1) = "C11"
 saData(12,1) = "F11"
 saData(13,1) = "C13"
 saData(14,1) = "F13"

 Dim count : count = 16
 For i = 15 to 54
     saData(i,1) = "D" count
     count = count + 1
     next'

saData(55,1) = "G59"
saData(56,1) = "F60"
saData(57,1) = "B64"
saData(58,1) = "E64"

For i = 0 to 59
    Msgbox saData(i,1)
    next
```

Comment: Add to the begin:
ReDim Preserve saData(60,1)

Comment: Yes that would solve my problem, thank you for taking the time. After going over my code many more times, I observed that I'm trying to fill the array wrong. The array is created using statement " Dim saData(2, 59) " my code is clearly trying to put a sting in rows that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just try concatenating `saData(i,1) = "D"&count`